# How do I upload a single file to a server from Gradle

Tags: gradle

I have looked everywhere for this seemingly simple task but can find no way to do it without either Maven or Ivy, neither of which I want to use. I just want to find a way to create a task that can upload an arbitrary file to a server without needing metadata of any sort besides credentials to the server, the file path and the URL. I realize I could write this in Groovy but I feel like there must be some built in way to do this with a Gradle task that doesn't involve hacking. Thank you very much for reading this far!

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search found this: https://gist.github.com/chilicat/6486392 .  This and the reference in the comment should be enough options.